# Stop Reload of my php page after x reloads?

Tags: php, refresh, counter, reload

i got the header for reloading my page header("Refresh:5");. Can i stop reloading after x*reloads, maybe with a counter or something like that?

Comment: Use Javascript!

Comment: I shall not use java for my page. Thats the problem.

Comment: Yes, you will need to count the amount of page loads somewhere and somehow then. You could try and set the current count in a cookie, or you can pass it as a GET parameter via the URL. Then based on the value you receive, you decide whether you still output the code that triggers the reload, or not.

Comment: Not `Java` use `JavaScript` !

Comment: Is it possible at all to prevent browser click on reload? If so I'm 100% confident it will not work in Safari. Regarding the PHP side, what do you want to do when user reloads page more than 5 times? To throw him an error - "reload limit exhausted"?)))

Comment: My side has to reload till i get something like a confirmation from a database but it should stop after a x amount of time.

Comment: Not: Java is NOT javascript. They are two very separate languages !
Also, why won't you used javascript ? Can't ? Dont want to ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used PHP in so long I can't give an implementation example but,
from a "general web" point of view, I think the simplest solution without using Javascript would be to have a session variable storing the number of times the refresh occured and then use a conditional statement on the value of this session variable to decide whether to include or omit the refresh header.

Reference on the usage of session variables:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Sample untested code:

In your page use `$_SESSION["refreshCount"] = $_SESSION["refreshCount"] + 1`

and around your header use

```
IF($_SESSION["refreshCount"] <= x
{
    header("Refresh:5");
}
```